# How filter works in this function?

Tags: javascript, filter

I wrote this code while ago and now when I look at it I don't understand what "upPrice" doing here. Is is a variable? If so, how it works without declaration? If it is function parameter, I didn't passed it anywhere. Please help me to understand what it is and how it works.

```
 const items = [
    { name: 'Bike', price: 100 },
    { name: 'TV', price: 200 },
    { name: 'Album', price: 10 },
    { name: 'Book', price: 5 },
    { name: 'Phone', price: 500 },
    { name: 'Computer', price: 1000 },
    { name: 'Keyboard', price: 25 },

]
const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => upPrice = item.price > 50)
console.log(filteredItems);
```

When I delete upPrice, code still works. But I want to understand what is it?

Comment: variables can be declared without `var`/`let`/`const` in sloppy mode. When you do that, they become a global variable by default. It's not recommended, and it's "banned" in strict mode as it will throw an error (meaning it won't work in modules, classes, or places where you've used the "use strict" directive)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`upPrice` isn't actually doing much in that function. The expression `item.price > 50` is being stored into `upPrice`, which will always be a boolean value - and that value is "returned" to the filter function, which determines if that item should be kept or filtered out.

So really `upPrice =` can be removed safely.

Caveat: You may want to check if you have a global variable (or nearby local variable) named `upPrice`, as I believe you could be updating that variable from within the `filter` function... Though this seems like very bad practice & I would definitely never recommend doing that :D

Comment: But how it could be stored in variable which I didn't declared with keywords 'const' or 'let' ? Sorry if question is silly, but I want to understand it :)

Comment: That's just how JavaScript works - you don't "have to" declare a variable with `let` or `const` - you can even declare `items` with `items = [...` if you want to (again I don't recommend doing that)

Comment: So you can even try this:
1. Before your `const items = [` line, write `let upPrice = true`
2. Add `upPrice` to your console log like this: `console.log(filteredItems, upPrice);`
You'll see that `upPrice` turned to `false` because you updated that variable from within your filter function

Answer (score 2):

It can also be written like this:

```
const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => {
  upPrice = item.price > 50;
  return upPrice;
})
```

You can declare a variable without var/let/const. It just creates it as a global variable. Not usually desired.

upPrice is storing the result of "is item.price greater than 50?", a boolean value which is used to decide whether or not to filter out the current item.

Really, upPrice isn't needed. You can just return the boolean value directly without storing it first:

```
const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => {
  return item.price > 50;
})
```

Or:

```
const filteredItems = items.filter((item) => item.price > 50)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are here filtering data of const items and in that lambda
function you are just storing into `upprice` nothing more it is waste of memory nothing else

if you remove it though you can do it as you mentioned earlier